# Bitbucket Webhooks for running Appium tests

Tags: appium, webhooks, webdriver-io, bitbucket-pipelines, browserstack-app-automate

I have repository with the WDIO+Appium+Browserstack tests on Bitbucket. My developers team has another repository for building app (for Android and iOS). When they have built new app version they pushed it directly to the Browserstack and I want to run my tests after this step.

I want to prepare some webhook so when new app version was uploaded on Browserstack my Appium tests will be triggered and run in pipeline (in my repository).

How to do it? I have looked through the Bitbucket documentation but I did not figure out how to create webhook for link 2 repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can push in their repository, easiest setup would be their release pipeline actively triggering your test pipeline with https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?category=workflowautomation&p=atlassian/trigger-pipeline